# Laravel hadManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel

So I have 3 models `User`, `League` and `Submission`. I am trying to query all the `leagues` a `user` has had `submissions` to.

the Dbs look like:

Users

```
Standard Laravel users table
```

Leagues

```
id | name | description
```

Submissions

```
id | user_id | league_id
```

in my `user` model I have

```
public function joinedLeagues()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\League', 'App\Submission');
    }
```

but this returns nothing. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent would inspect the `user_id` on the intermediate `submissions` table, after finding the matching submission IDs, they would be used to query the `leagues` table. You tables must look like this:

users:

```
id - interger
name - string
```

submissions:

```
id - integer
user_id - integer
name - string
description - string
```

leagues:

```
id - integer
name - string
submission_id - integer
```

Comment: That wont work because leagues have a ton of submissions through another model. Is there no way to get all the leagues via submission? Maybe I will just do a custom DB query.

Comment: What is the fourth model? what's the relationship between them?

Comment: it would be `wod` with a Many to Many. So `leagues` have many` wods`. `Wods` have many `Submissions`. `Submission` in the db have `league_id `and `wod_id` and `user_id`. So to get all the `leagues` a `user` is in, we look at all the `submissions`

Comment: There's relationships are not `hasManyThrough`, `uses` has many `submissions` and `leagues` has many `submissions`.

Comment: So, if you want to get all the `leagues` a `user` is in, you should get all the `submissions` and then  in a loop of that get all the `leagues`.

Comment: Or if you in consideration of performance, after you get all the `submissions`  , get all the league IDs in a loop, then to get all `leagues` with league IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did now that I know there is a `findMany` query with Laravel

```
public function joinedLeagues()
    {
        //Make and empty array
        $league_ids   = array();

        //Get all submissions from the user
        $submissions  = Auth::user()->submissions;

        foreach ($submissions as $submission) {
           //Add the league id to the array
           array_push($league_ids, $submission->league_id);
        }

        //Now find the leagues based off submissions
        $leagues =  League::findMany($league_ids);

        return $leagues;
    }
```